# Pass complex object between pages in C#

Tags: c#, object, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I am using this code to pass values in my Windows 8 app.

The following code passes data to a page when an item is clicked, So it passes sectorId to the Quiz page.

```
private void quizbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var sectorId = "Items1";

            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Quiz), sectorId);
        }
```

The Quiz page receives the passed parameter `sectorId` in the load page function where `Object navigationParameter` is the `sectorId` passed.

```
protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {
        }
```

I want to make the object passed, that is, `sectorId` more complex so that it does not just include the string of text "Items1", but Includes the string of text, and index, and a value representing a total(int).

How do I pass this complex object and load it on the page?

Comment: Are you asking how to declare and instantiate a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Frame.Navigate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702394.aspx) method takes an `object` as a parameter, and really doesn't care what type of `object` it is.  You can create any kind of object and pass it as the second parameter.

```
public struct QuizArgs
{
    public string Question;
    public string[] Answers;
    public int CorrectIndex;
    public DateTime Timestamp;
}




private void quizbtn_Click(object Sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var args = new QuizArgs
    {
        Question = "What color is the sky?",
        Answers = new string[] { "Red", "Green", "Blue", "Silver" },
        CorrectIndex = 2,
        Timestamp = DateTime.Now
    };

    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Quiz), args);
}
```

And in your `Quiz` class:

```
protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
{
    if (navigationParameter == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("navigatyionParameter");
    QuizArgs args = navigationParameter as QuizArgs;
    if (args == null)
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Incorrect type '{0}'", navigationParameter.GetType().Name), "navigationParameter");

    // Do something with the 'args' data here
}
```

Comment: Don't do this.  Passing complex objects as a Navigation Parameter will cause your app to crash on resume from suspension (as per here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049589/windows-store-apps-my-app-terminates-after-being-switched);

Comment: You can serialize your complex object, pass it as a string then deserialize the string at the second page

Answer (score 0):

Passing data between pages is usually done using the query-string (GET) or by using a form (POST).  You cannot really pass a complex object between pages, unless you serialize it to a string first and then use the before mentioned methods (GET/POST), but that's not recommended due to length restrictions.

However, you can use the session state and/or the application state to store complex objects (as long as they are serializable) and use them across different requests.

Comment: The OP tagged the question 'windows-8', so he's maybe asking about a Metro UI app…

Comment: This is for a Windows 8 desktop app. Would it apply here?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were talking about a web app.  For a windows/metro UI app, things are very different.