# Windows Store Apps: my app terminates after being switched

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm building a Windows 8 app.

My problem is when the user switches to another app or goes to start, the app terminates.
In the side bar I find the preview of the app to be displaying the splash screen, when I click on the app it starts from the beginning.

What can be the problem here, could it be a memory issue ? In the task manager my app takes 40 MB of memory, is that too much ?

---

### EDIT

---

The **Event Viewer** shows the following when the app crashes:

> Application: MyApp.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The
>   process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
>   MyApp.Common.SuspensionManagerException Stack:    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext+Invoker.b__0(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

Comment: If you debug it. are there any exceptions thrown?

Comment: Is the app crashing at all? Does it do it when you are debugging? Have you changed the `OnActivation` functions at all? Are there any Events being thrown in the EventViewer?

Comment: The app doesn't crash when debugging, however the EventViewer shows the error details as in the update of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your stack trace it looks like the suspension manager is throwing an exception.  The most common cause of exceptions I've found in the suspension manager is in trying to pass complex objects between pages as a navigation parameter.  If you are passing a complete business object around, then try just passing the ID.  I know it's crazy, but that's the way it is with the default implementation.

Comment: Thanks, I was saving the whole ViewModel object to the PageState, when I removed it the app worked normally.