# How to pass multiple arguments between windows store pages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-store-apps

Following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx) msdn tutorial it shows how to pass argument from one page to another.

```
private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BasicPage2), tb1.Text);
}

private void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    string name = e.NavigationParameter as string;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
    {
        tb1.Text = "Hello, " + name;
    }
    else
    {
        tb1.Text = "Name is required.  Go back and enter a name.";
    }
}
```

But How do I pass multiple arguments ?

I need to pass 2 collections(2 lists to be specific). How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to pass two collection create a class and initialize your collection inside the class and pass it as a argument.

```
class collectionscontainer
{
  private list<urlist> list1;
  private list<urlist> list1;
}
Class Classname
{
  public void Methord(collectionscontainer c)
  {
    //hear u will get access of both lists 
  } 
}
```

Comment: I guess that's what needs to be done. I am only worried because accepted answer from [Pass complex object between pages in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035668/pass-complex-object-between-pages-in-c-sharp) has comment "Passing complex objects as a Navigation Parameter will cause your app to crash on resume from suspension (as per here [stackoverflow.com/questions/20049589/…](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049589/windows-store-apps-my-app-terminates-after-being-switched) );"